# Why is react props empty in child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have child menu:

```
    export default class TopMenuPage extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            console.log(props)
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                activeItem: 'overview',
            }
            console.log(this.props)
        }



        render = () => {
            return (
                <div>
                    TEST
                </div >
            )
        }

}
```

I am including this menu in parent like this:

```
        render = () => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <TopMenuPage />
                </div >
            )
        }
```

When is constructor of child component TopMenuPage is called, props are empty. Why?

Output is:
{}
{}

I don't understand why. I need read url from props.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need to pass props to the `TopMenuPage` component from the parent. Something close to `<TopMenuPage  {...props}/>`

Comment: props is empty because you are not passing any props when calling <TopMenuPage /> component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call your `TopMenuPage` in the parent compoenent you are not passing any props to the `TopMenuPage` component, In order for you to do that. You can do it like below.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
     <TopMenuPage name="Menu" isShowing={true} foo="bar" />
    </div >
  );
}
```

This way when in your `TopMenuPage` constructor you log using `console.log(this.props)` you will see the following result in your `console`

```
{ 
   name: 'Menu,
   isShowing: true,
   foo: 'bar'
}
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer that you were looking for, Kindly mark it as the answer. @nope123